# Divide a sum formula by the total of cells that have a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wanting to work out the average miles per gallon of our vehicle fleet.

I have the total *miles per gallon* in a tab that is summing each figure from **15** other tabs.

I would like to divide this *total* figure by the number of vehicles that were working on that day i.e. divide sum formula by the total of cells that have a value in.

I am aiming to exclude any cells that do not have a value from the division

I am also not wanting to divide by the value in the cell, but by the **NUMBER** of cells that contain a value.

Comment: You can use COUNTA function to count the non blank cells. You will have to apply this to the range where your info about vehicle is in your sheet. You may like to share a screenshot of your sheet for better clarity.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly and provide some sample data.  I can’t make any sense of what you’re saying.  My best understanding of what you’re saying is as follows: You have 15 vehicles, but only 3 of them were active.  For simplicity, *each one* of them drove 200 miles and burned 10 gallons, so 600 miles ÷ 30 gallons = 20 miles per gallon, total.  And you want to divide that number by 3, yielding 6.666.  Which has no bearing on the real world.

Comment: And of course the OP isn’t going to respond, because this is a drive-by question — the OP hasn’t been seen since Feb 2 ’17, the day after the question was asked.   Burn it to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Using `COUNTA(range_of_cells_to_count_non_blanks)` to calculate your denominator is the neatest, most succinct way to do this.

You could also use `=COUNTIF(range_of_cells_to_count_non_blanks, "<>")` to calculate your denominator, but why would you when `COUNTA` works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

hope this shed some light to your problem. As you never gave any DATA example I tried to gather some ideas that you may find useful.

Total Distance = `=SUMIF(B2:B7;"Working";D2:D7)`

Total Cars = `=COUNTIF(B2:B7;"<>")`

Total MPG = `=G3/G4`

Total fuel price = `=G5*G1`

Cheers.

[image]